# PHP writing Class and id as single quotes instead of double quotes. Why?

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am getting a lot of errors lately on a Joomla project and have found things like (in class code)...

```
return "<span class='...
```

or

```
echo "<h3 id='...
```

instead of

```
return "<span class=\"...
echo "<h3 id=\"...
```

This includes many times a variable in quotes, but it still finds it's way to my browser with single quotes. Before going through and changing these, I wanted to see what others have to say. My project is at http://dev.thediabetesnetwork.com.

I have looked this up and find a lot of conflicting information, so figured I would revive the discussion for the newest PHP/browser configurations and see if I am overlooking other details.

Comment: If it's a Joomla project, shouldn't this have the `joomla` tag?

Comment: @Jon, Are you referring to something in the footer telling everyone we are using Joomla? Or something else?

Comment: KingCrunch did what I was referring to. Take a look at his edit to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a lot easier to read without all the double quotes inside the string being escaped with `\`.

If you need to output a variable inside a string expression, double quotes must be used.  If you are outputting HTML inside double-quotes, you can either use `'` or `\"` to enclose HTML attributes.  The first is preferred because it results in cleaner PHP code.

If you don't want your HTML to use single quotes, then you can just escape all of your quotes, use [heredoc syntax](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), or concatenate your variables into the string like:

```
echo '<div class="test">' . $var . '</div>';
```

Comment: Yes I have seen that and it looks a lot cleaner imo. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Browser accept both, thus there is no deeper reason to choose one before the other. From the PHP point-of-view it is slightly more readable with single quotes, because you can wrap strings in double quotes and use variable substition. Compare yourself

```
"<a href='$url'>Foo</a>"
"<a href=\"$url\">Foo</a>"
'<a href="' . $url . '">Foo</a>'
```

Another solution is to substitute the content manually, for example

```
sprintf('<a href="%s">Foo</a>', $url);
```

Or heredoc

```
echo <<<HTML
<a href="$url">Foo</a>
HTML;
```

I would choose the one, that fits best into the current context (regarding the readability).

Comment: Thanks, I see it working, but validation is getting errors and that looks like a different conflict. I just wanted to get rid of any code that works intermittently, but it looks like that is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use double quotes if the string doesn't need evaluating (e.g. if it contains variables, etc). In fact, because double quotes causes the string to be evaluated, they're less efficient than using single quotes and concatenating.

Furthermore, it's convention to use double quotes inside HTML tags, so this is how I'd do it:

```
return '<span class="test">' . $var . '</span>';
```

In my opinion, Joomla is very poorly coded, and what you've posted is just another example of this.

Another advantage to this method, as you can see above, is that code highlighters and IEDs make it easy to differentiate between "static" strings and variables.

Comment: "it's convention"? Whose convention is it? ;) There are some very popular code conventions, that handle it this way, but you should not treat it as "the general php-way-of-life". This efficiency is negligable and is usually "premature optimization"/"micro optimization".

Comment: The convention is using double quotes in HTML tags (`class="test"`).  The efficiency comes from surrounding strings with single quotes and concatenating.  Whilst the advantage is small, it's still worth considering.

Comment: No, it's not. The difference is not measureable in real world scenarios and the mess it creates, when more than 2 variables are involved, isn't worth it. But again: You shouldn't say "_the_ convention", if there isn't "_the_ convention". The one, that comes closest to this definition is PSR1/PSR2 and both don't mention quotes. When you refer a concrete one, you should name it to avoid confusion.

Comment: For the second time "the convention" that I'm talking about is NOT related to PHP.  The convention refers to the use of double quotes inside HTML tags- nothing to do with PHP and equally as applicable in "raw" HTML markup.  The SEPARATE ISSUE is the use of single quotes for PHP strings, which in this case just happens to include HTML.  Yes, the performance advantage is very small, but the other advantage (probably more important, depending on your view point) is readability.

Answer (score 1):

Double quote and single quotes have different functionality in php.

You can put a variable or even array into a string with double quotes but not so with single quotes.

Both are acceptable in HTML specification.  Indeed even no quotes is if there's not spaces.  Most people prefer that I know to have double quotes for the php so you can use variables without breaking up your code and readability because no backslashes.

```
return "<span class='foo'>$foo</span>";
return "<span class=\"foo\">$foo</span>";
return '<span class="foo">'.$foo.'</span>';
return '<span class=\'foo\'>'.$foo.'</span>';
```

All work but the first one, to most, is the easiest to read and type.

You can read all about php strings, double quotes, single quotes, heredoc and nowdoc syntax in php's documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

```
echo <<<EOT
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

Is example Heredoc syntax which allows you to pick your starting and ending delimeters for long multiline strings.  Nowdoc is the same as heredoc but like single quotes, you can't put variables into the string.